# Compile Error in Access Form Code

Tags: vba, ms-access

In some code for a Form I am building there is an Add function I am working on and when I fill in all the fields and click the button and then it highlights a certain portion and gives me the COMPILE ERROR: METHOD OR DAT MEMBER NOT FOUND and I cannot troubleshoot the problem the code is:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO CDData(Gender, EEOC, EmployeeID, EmployeeName, ReadinessLevel, Division, Center, EmployeeFeedback, DevelopmentForEmployee, Justification, Changed) " & _
    " VALUES ('" & Me.cboGender & "','" & Me.cboEEOC & "','" & Me.txtID & "','" & Me.txtName & "','" & Me.cboReady & "','" & Me.txtDivision & "','" & Me.txtCenter & "','" & Me.txtFeedback & "','" & _
    Me.txtDevelopment & "','" & Me.txtJustification & "','" & Me.cboChanged & "') "
```

And the portion highlighted with the error is:
    .txtName

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use a string variable, `strInsert`, to hold the `INSERT` statement.  Then `Debug.Print strInsert` before you do `CurrentDb.Execute strInsert`.  Go to the Immediate window to view the output from `Debug.Print`.  Copy the statement text and paste into SQL View of a new Access query for testing.  If you need more help, paste the statement text into your question and tell us what error message Access gives you when you try to execute that query from the query designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like your previous question, I'm compelled to believe txtName isn't an actual control on your form.  Double-check to make sure it exists and it exists on the form.  If it's anything other than a textbox, you may need to add ".Value" to it.

One thing you can do is add a series of messageboxes to your code for testing purposes (remove them before you roll it out) so you will know exactly what you're dealing with.  You could do something like:

```
MsgBox "Here are the values: Gender - " & Me.cboGender & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & " & _ 
"EEOC - " & Me.cboEEOC  & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & " & _
"EmployeeID - " & Me.txtID & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & " & _ 
"EmployeeName - " & Me.txtName & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & ""
```

You can add the rest in a similar fashion.  The "Chr(13) & Chr(10)" will force a line feed so it looks a little nicer.  Anyway, this will tell you what Access thinks the values fo all your textboxes are, which might help you determine where your error is.

Comment: This was a whole new form, I figured it out though and your original solution also worked.